# alter the view output in drupal 7

Tags: drupal, view

I am using a view that builds up an output using several fileds in a drupal view.

the output is then print to screen but i am adding ',' after some of the items using rewrite. The problem is on some of my outputs i have a '.' then im adding a ',' giving me '.,' which is a bit odd.

What i'm wanting to do is to alter my veiw output before it is print to screen.

I am currently trying the following:

```
  function mymodule_views_pre_render(&$view) {

     switch($view -> name){
            case  "publications" :
                  foreach($view -> result as $res){
            $res -> title = rtrim($res -> title, '.');
                        }
            break;
     }
  }
```

This works for title but some of the fields are nodes so I cannot use this method.

Ideally i would prefer to edit the output HTML. I need to do this in a module and not a template.

Can this be done? 
any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to do this for every field in your view?  If so, you can override the generic field template for that view:

views-view-field--.tpl.php

then you can:

```
<?php print rtrim($output, '.'); . ','?>
```

To remove periods at the end of a string, then add a ","

Comment: $output cant be used in this way in drupal 7. I used $rows. This works a treat.